# Refactorings on a Win32 Screenshot saving program

Tags: c++, image, windows

Earlier this academic year I had an assignment to take a project I had written outside the context of University and apply a number of refactorings to it.

I chose a program I had written a while ago that saves periodic 24-bit lossless bitmap screenshots of a user-specified target window.

BMPTimer Class:

```
// Header for BMPTimer
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include "BMPWriter.h"
/**
 * BMPTimer class - a timer for periodically saving screenshots of a specified window.
 */
class CBMPTimer
{
private:
    int ticks_so_far; // New variable added with refactor #3 - keeps track of ticks made by our timer
    int ms_interval; // Inteval between clicks
    HWND hwTarget; // Target window
    HANDLE hThread; // Thread for timer tick
    LPVOID thistimer; // Pointer to "this" class instance
    static bool timeractive; // Flag for exitting the timer thread
public:
    // Stub that invokes threadproc (required for using a callback function belonging to a class)
    static DWORD StaticThreadProc(LPVOID);
    // Actual thread procedure
    DWORD ThreadProc(LPVOID);
    // Sets the exit flag condition for the thread proc
    void StopTimer();
    // Constructor/deconstructor
    CBMPTimer(HWND, int);
    ~CBMPTimer();
};

#include "BMPTimer.h"
bool CBMPTimer::timeractive;
/**
 * Class constructor for CBMPTimer
 * Takes a handle to the target window for screenshotting
 *  and an interval in milliseconds.
 */
CBMPTimer::CBMPTimer(HWND hWnd, int ms)
{
    // Assign member variables
    hwTarget = hWnd;
    ms_interval = ms;
    // This cast is necessary so that the ThreadProc function can be called from a static stub
    thistimer = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(this);
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&StaticThreadProc, thistimer, 0, NULL);
    // Set other member variables...
    timeractive = true;
    ticks_so_far=0;
}
/**
 * Class deconstructor for CBMPTimer
 * Frees dynamically allocated memory
 */
CBMPTimer::~CBMPTimer()
{
    delete thistimer;
}
// Stub method that invokes ThreadProc.
// Necessary so that ThreadProc can belong to the class and also be specified as a callback function.
DWORD CBMPTimer::StaticThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    CBMPTimer *pThis = reinterpret_cast<CBMPTimer*>(lpParam);
    return pThis->ThreadProc(lpParam);
}
// Actual thread procedure.
// Uses a CBMPWriter object to save a bitmap of the target window as long as the flag to keep running stays on.
DWORD CBMPTimer::ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
{   
    while (timeractive)
    {
        Sleep(ms_interval);
        CBMPWriter bmpW(hwTarget, ++ticks_so_far);
        bmpW.SaveBMP();
        bmpW.~CBMPWriter();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

BMPWriter class:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/**
 * BMPWriter class - a file writer for bitmap screenshots of a given window.
 */
class CBMPWriter
{
private:
    char *data; // Stores the array of bits representing a bitmap of a window
    int len_data; // Length of data
    //char fname[MAX_PATH]; // Filename to write out
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfHeader; // Bitmap file header structure
    BITMAPINFOHEADER biHeader; // Bitmap file header #2 structure
    BITMAPINFO bInfo; // Bitmap file header #3 structure
    HBITMAP hBitmap; // Handle to the bitmap object
    HWND hwTarget; // Target window
    HDC windowDC, tempDC; // Device context for target window and temporary copy in memory
    int count; // Refactor #3 - generate file names internally rather than use lazy class CFileNameGenerator
    int xd, yd; // x and y dimensions of bitmap
public:
    char fname[MAX_PATH]; // Filename to write out
    // Generate next file name of bitmap file - refactored out of CFileNameGenerator
    string NextFileName();
    // Initialization functions for the 3 bitmap file header/signature structs
    void InitFH();
    void InitIH();
    void InitInfo();    
    // Class constructor - calls the initialization functions
    CBMPWriter(HWND, int);
    // Deconstructor - cleans up GDI objects and frees memory
    ~CBMPWriter();
    // Performs the actual bitmap file write
    void SaveBMP();
};


#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "BMPWriter.h"

// Generates the next filename to write out the bitmap data to.
string CBMPWriter::NextFileName()
{
    string next_filename;
    int temp = count;
    // Get the number of digits in the count variable by using logarithm base 10
    int num_digits = (int)log10(temp)+1;
    char tmp[32];
    // Write out the ascii value of the count into the string
    for(int i = 0; i < num_digits; i++)
    {
        tmp[num_digits-i-1]=(temp%10)+'0'; // digits 0-9 plus ascii '0' = char representation
        temp/=10; // divide by 10 to process next place-value
    }
    tmp[num_digits]=0; // terminate string with null char
    // create final filename string and return it.
    string countstr = tmp;
    next_filename="shot_";
    next_filename+=countstr;
    next_filename+=".bmp";
    return next_filename;
}

/** Initalizes the fields in the bitmap file header - file signature, header size, etc... */
void CBMPWriter::InitFH()
{
    bfHeader.bfType = 0x4d42;  // magic number- identifies the file as a valid bitmap to image viewers etc.
    bfHeader.bfSize = 0;     // This and other 3 are reserved and always 0
    bfHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bfHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bfHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);  // Specifies the number of bytes occupied by the headers (before the actual array of bits/pixels begins)
}

/** Initalizes the bitmap info header structure - bit intensity, planes, dimensions etc... */
void CBMPWriter::InitIH()
{
    biHeader.biSize = sizeof(biHeader);
    biHeader.biBitCount = 24; // 24-bits = full intensity/lossless RGB image of window
    biHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB; // No compression
    biHeader.biHeight = yd; // dimensions
    biHeader.biWidth = xd;
    biHeader.biPlanes = 1; // number of planes
    biHeader.biSizeImage = 0; // all reserved fields below, must be 0
    biHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    biHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    biHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    biHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
}
// Initializes the bInfo structure (not a file header but necessary for various bitmap WinAPI functions)
void CBMPWriter::InitInfo()
{
    bInfo.bmiHeader = biHeader;
}

CBMPWriter::CBMPWriter(HWND window, int tick)
{
    // Set local variables...
    RECT r;
    hwTarget = window;
    count = tick;
    // Get the file name to save for this instance of CBMPWriter
    strcpy(fname, NextFileName().c_str());
    // Get dimensions...
    GetWindowRect(hwTarget, &r);
     xd = r.right - r.left;
     yd = r.bottom - r.top;
    count=0;
    // Initialize file/bitmap headers and signatures etc
    InitFH();
    InitIH();
    InitInfo();

    // Calculate length of data.
    len_data = ((((24 * xd + 31)&(~31)) / 8)*yd);
    // Generate dynamic char (byte) array based on length.
    data = new char[len_data];
    // Get the device context of the target window
    windowDC = GetWindowDC(hwTarget);
    // Create a new device context *in memory* with identical properties as the window DC
    tempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(windowDC);
    // Get the bitmap of the window
    hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(windowDC, &bInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&data, 0, 0);
    // Select it as the GDI object we want to use
    SelectObject(tempDC, hBitmap);
    // And copy it into the memory device context 
    BitBlt(tempDC, 0, 0, xd, yd, windowDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

/**
 * Class deconstructor for CBMPWriter
 * Deletes GDI objects, frees dynamic memory, etc. to prevent memory leaks
 */
CBMPWriter::~CBMPWriter()
{
    DeleteDC(tempDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwTarget, windowDC);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}

// Performs the actual write of the bitmap.
void CBMPWriter::SaveBMP()
{
    // Create a file (if we can)
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(fname, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile)
    {
        // If we can, write out the headers, then write out the bitmap
        DWORD dwWritten = 0;
        WriteFile(hFile, &bfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, &biHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, data, len_data, &dwWritten, NULL);
    }
    else // If not, tell the user, and exit the class function
    {
        MessageBox(0, _T("Could not open the file."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
    }
    // Free handle from memory.
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

MsgHandler class:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include "BMPTimer.h"
/**
 * CMsgHandler class - does the "dirty work" of the window procedure (handle messages etc).
 * Refactor #4 - existence of this class
 */
class CMsgHandler
{
private:
    // The *target window* of the bitmap captures. Must be static as this class is created/deconstructed for each message posted to the queue.
    static HWND hwTarget;
    // The child windows of the parent screenshot taking app window.
    HWND hWnd, hwCmdSource, hStartBtn, hStopBtn, hSelect, hStatic2;
    // The identifier of the message (WM_whatever)
    UINT Msg;
    // WPARAM and LPARAM passed to the message 
    WPARAM wParam;
    LPARAM lParam;
    // Bitmap timer class (necessary on start call)
    CBMPTimer *bmpT;
    // Return value
    LRESULT return_val;
public:
    // Refactor #5 - remove the various redundant calls to FindWindowEx with all but 1 identical parameters
    inline HWND FindWindowQ(LPCWSTR className, LPCWSTR winText);
    // The various message handlers.
    VOID Handle_Close();
    VOID Handle_Destroy();
    VOID Handle_Command();
    VOID Handle_Generic();

    // Sub-handlers for WM_COMMAND based on command source
    VOID Handle_Start();
    VOID Handle_Stop();
    VOID Handle_Select();

    // Return the return value (required for WindowProc stub)
    LRESULT Get_Return();

    // Constructor/deconstructor
    CMsgHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, HWND hStaticW);
    ~CMsgHandler();
};



#include "MsgHandler.h"
// Macros for eliminating duplicated code - simplifies method calls to FindWindowEx
#define FINDBUTTON(wtxt) (FindWindowQ((TEXT("BUTTON")), (L##wtxt)))
#define FINDEDIT (FindWindowQ((TEXT("EDIT")), (NULL)))
HWND CMsgHandler::hwTarget;
// Inline method for handling calls to FindWIndowEx - removes necessity for several duplicated calls etc
inline HWND CMsgHandler::FindWindowQ(LPCWSTR className, LPCWSTR winText)
{
    return FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, className, winText);
}

// Handles the WM_CLOSE message (destroys the window, return 0)
VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Close()
{
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    return_val = (LRESULT)0;
}

// Handles the WM_DESTROY message (posts the exit code for the window; return 0)
VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Destroy()
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return_val = (LRESULT)0;
}

// Stub method to handle all calls not specifically supported by our class (call DefWindowProc)
VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Generic()
{
    return_val = DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

// Handles the WM_COMMAND message
VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Command()
{
    // Step 1: identify the source of the command (which button)
     hwCmdSource = (HWND)lParam;
    // Step 2: pass to the appropriate sub-handle for WM_COMMAND based on the button
    if (hwCmdSource == hSelect)
    {
        Handle_Select();
    }
    if (hwCmdSource == hStartBtn)
    {
        if (hwTarget == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Please first select a target window!"), TEXT("Problem"), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            return_val = (LRESULT)0;
            return;
        }
        Handle_Start();
    }
    if (hwCmdSource == hStopBtn)
    {
        Handle_Stop();
    }
    return_val = (LRESULT)0;
}

// Class constructor for CMsgHandler 
//  sets up member variables and determines which message handler to use
CMsgHandler::CMsgHandler(HWND ahWnd, UINT aMsg, WPARAM awParam, LPARAM alParam, HWND hStaticW)
{
    hWnd = ahWnd;
    Msg = aMsg;
    wParam = awParam;
    lParam = alParam;

    hStartBtn = FINDBUTTON("Start");
    hStopBtn = FINDBUTTON("Stop");
    hSelect = FINDBUTTON("Select Window");

    hStatic2 = hStaticW;
    if (Msg == WM_CLOSE) Handle_Close();
    else if (Msg == WM_DESTROY) Handle_Destroy();
    else if (Msg == WM_COMMAND) Handle_Command();
    else Handle_Generic();
}

// Sub handler for "select window" WM_COMMAND message source
// Asks the user for the window they want to target,
//  prints out info about target window on app window
VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Select()
{
    MessageBox(0, TEXT("If you are targetting a usual Windows application, try to target the *title bar* of the application.  If you are targetting a Java or Flash applet target anywhere within the applet.\n\nPress OK and then hover your mouse over the target window within 2 seconds... (before pressing OK, you can move this message box closer to your target if need be)"), TEXT("Info"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
    Sleep(2000);
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    hwTarget = WindowFromPoint(p);
    TCHAR wndTxt[255];
    SendMessage(hwTarget, WM_GETTEXT, 255, (LPARAM)wndTxt);
    TCHAR sttcbuf[1024];
    RECT wRect;
    GetWindowRect(hwTarget, &wRect);
    wsprintf(sttcbuf, TEXT("Target Window: %s\n(handle = 0x%.8X; rect=(%d,%d)-(%d,%d))"), wndTxt, hwTarget, wRect.left, wRect.top, wRect.right, wRect.bottom);
    SetWindowText(hStatic2, sttcbuf);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);

}

// Handles the "Start" WM_COMMAND message
// 1. Toggles the enabled state of start and stop button
// 2. intializes a CBMPTimer with the specified target and specified interval.
VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Start()
{
    EnableWindow((HWND)lParam, FALSE);
    EnableWindow(FINDBUTTON("Stop"), TRUE);
    int len = GetWindowTextLength((FINDEDIT)) + 1;
    TCHAR *lenBuf = new TCHAR[len];
    GetWindowText(FINDEDIT, lenBuf, len);
    int ms = _wtoi(lenBuf);
    if (ms == 0)ms++;
    bmpT = new CBMPTimer(hwTarget, ms);
}

// Handles a "Stop" WM_COMMAND message
// 1. Stops the running CBMPTimer 
// 2. Toggles the enabled state of start and stop button

VOID CMsgHandler::Handle_Stop()
{
    bmpT->StopTimer();
    EnableWindow((HWND)lParam, FALSE);
    EnableWindow(FINDBUTTON("Start"), TRUE);
}

CMsgHandler::~CMsgHandler()
{

}
// Returns the stored LRESULT to WindowProc stub.
LRESULT CMsgHandler::Get_Return()
{
    return return_val;
}
```

WinMain (global namespace):

```
// The below files include my self-written classes for this project.
#include "BMPWriter.h"
#include "BMPTimer.h"
#include "MsgHandler.h"
const TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("ScreenSnapperWnd");
// The below two files allow for necessary Windows API and Process API functions in this project
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include "Global.h"
HWND hwTarget = (HWND)0x0000000, hStaticWI = (HWND)0x00000000, hWnd, hStart, hStop, hFindTarget, hTimerMS, hStaticE;

/** Refactor #1:
 * Given the length of WinMain, extract some methods from it, namely, the initialization of the WNDCLASSEX structure 
 */
ATOM RegisterWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.style = CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW | CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT | CS_GLOBALCLASS;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

/**
 * Still Refactor #1 - extract child Window initialization from WinMain into a new method.
 */
#define WS_RCHILD (WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD)
VOID CreateChildWindows()
{
    hStaticE = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Enter the interval between screenshots (milliseconds):"), WS_RCHILD, 0, 0, 270, 20, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    hTimerMS = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("5000"), WS_RCHILD | ES_NUMBER, 0, 22, 270, 20, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    hFindTarget = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Select Window"), WS_RCHILD | BS_TEXT, 10, 44, 250, 30, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    hStaticWI = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT(""), WS_RCHILD | SS_LEFT, 0, 88, 270, 40, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    hStart = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Start"), WS_RCHILD | BS_TEXT, 10, 130, 125, 30, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    hStop = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Stop"), WS_RCHILD | BS_TEXT | WS_DISABLED, 135, 130, 125, 30, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
}
/**
 * WinMain function - entry point for the application
 */
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{

    MSG Msg;

    if(!RegisterWindowClass(hInstance))
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, szClassName, TEXT("Screenshot Taker"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU, 100, 100, 290, 210, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    CreateChildWindows();

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumChildWindows(hWnd, SysFontProc, 0);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
// Callback function that sets all child windows of the screenshot taker window to the regular system font
BOOL CALLBACK SysFontProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HFONT hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, 0);
    return TRUE;
}
// Window procedure stub - required to be passed to WNDCLASSEX but invokes CMsgHandler to do all of the actual work
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CMsgHandler msghandler(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam, hStaticWI);
    return msghandler.Get_Return();
}
```

The `.h` files for the classes are first; the `.cpp` follows with the actual function bodies etc.

Though my grade on this assignment was good (95%), I'm curious if anyone can offer an outside opinion on the quality of my post-refactored code: is there anything that still smells bad in this code? What can be improved further?  Is this something I can safely call 'well-written'?

Comment: Did you test it with an OpenGl window? In my experience they do not get captured with a simple `BitBlt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a bit of code here, so this review is probably not complete:

### Coding style / Miscellaneous:

- Please keep parameter names on function prototypes. Parameter names
  are a form of self documentation of the code.
- I would like to see a blank line between each function, both in the header
  declarations and in the implementation. Your code is a bit cluttered in some places.
- Aligning things in a block such as this might also help readability
  (from `CBMPTimer`):

  ```
  int         ticks_so_far; // New variable added with refactor #3 - keeps track of ticks made by our timer
  int         ms_interval;  // Inteval between clicks
  HWND        hwTarget;     // Target window
  HANDLE      hThread;      // Thread for timer tick
  LPVOID      thistimer;    // Pointer to "this" class instance
  static bool timeractive;  // Flag for exitting the timer thread
  ```
- This is arguably personal preference, but I think it makes sense placing
  the **public** section of a class first. Since we read a file from top to bottom, 
  things at the top have more visibility. When a user of your class needs to consult
  a header file, what should have more visibility, private variables / implementation details,
  or the public interface?
- `using namespace std;` in a header file: **No, no**. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more.
- Poor spacing at places, for instance:

  ```
  next_filename="shot_";
  next_filename+=countstr;
  next_filename+=".bmp";
  ```

  Always put spaces between an assignment or arithmetical operator:

  ```
  next_filename = "shot_";
  next_filename += countstr;
  next_filename += ".bmp";
  ```
- `char fname[MAX_PATH]` should be an `std::string`.
- Use more [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Manual memory management is a dated practice
  that has proved time after time to lead to memory corruption bugs, dangling pointers and memory leaks.
- Be more mindful of your naming convention. You have mixed naming for
  variables, some are using `camelCase`, like in `hwTarget` while others 
  are using `snake_case`, like in `ticks_so_far`. Choose one notation and
  stick to it. Consistency is very important.
- If you can use C++11, then prefer the new [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) over the `NULL` macro.

### A few security problems and potential bugs:

- This is not technically legal in C++:

  ```
  hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&StaticThreadProc, thistimer, 0, NULL);
  ```

  You are passing a static class method (`CBMPTimer::StaticThreadProc`) as the thread's start routine.
  [`CreateThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx) expects a C function using the "WINAPI" (STD Call) calling convention. You have fixed that
  by applying a very unsafe cast to the function pointer. This is a crash waiting to happen. You have to declare
  the thread function as an extern C function using the adequate calling convention:

  ```
  extern "C" {

  DWORD WINAPI MyThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
  {
      CBMPTimer *pThis = reinterpret_cast<CBMPTimer*>(lpParam);
      return pThis->ThreadProc(lpParam);
  }

  } // extern C
  ```
- `delete thistimer;`, I don't even know how that is compiling. `thistimer` is a void pointer (`LPVOID`).
  `delete` shouldn't be able to delete `void*` because it has no type. This is probably being allowed by a Microsoft extension to the standard library.
- But `thistimer` get worse. It is actually a pointer to a `CBMPTimer` instance, initialized in `CBMPTimer`'s constructor:

  ```
  thistimer = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(this);
  ```

  So by trying to delete it in the destructor, you are attempting to delete a pointer to the class that is already being 
  destroyed. This is 100% Undefined Behavior.
- Manually calling a destructor:

  ```
  while (timeractive)
  {
      Sleep(ms_interval);
      CBMPWriter bmpW(hwTarget, ++ticks_so_far);
      bmpW.SaveBMP();
      bmpW.~CBMPWriter(); // <--- Not a good idea and also unnecessary.
  }
  ```

  Doing this is a bad idea. There are only a few rare cases where you'll 
  want to manually call a destructor. This is not one. The object is already 
  going out of scope, so it will be destroyed on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Few things surely do not look right.

- `~CBMPTimer` tries to delete an `int`. Good luck. It also doesn't stop the thread.
- Having no `BMPWriter.h` to review I may only suppose what `log10` is supposed to do. I also suppose that there's no place for floating point here, especially since `num_digits` has no relation to a capacity of `tmp`.
- It is very strange to see `NextFileName` be called from the constructor.
- I am sure that `0x4d42` has a proper name as a macro value (even a plain `BM` will do).

Comment: Added the header files - hope that clears some things up. `thistimer` is actually a pointer of type `void` (`LPVOID`)